# How to deploy a Rails + Webpacker app to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack, yarnpkg, webpacker

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 5 application to Heroku. It's the first time, however, that I added webpack to the equation.

I've used webpack to add some Vue components when needed. In my local environment everything works very well, however, things don't really go as planned when deploying to Heroku.

Precompiling the assets (both from the pipeline and webpack) completes. When I start the page where Vue is supposed to be running, however, in the console I see a 404 error when the browser is trying to retrieve the precompiled pack/main javascript file.

This is what Heroku logs show:

```
2017-10-19T10:04:51.947282+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/packs/main-49ef6f7f11bf1482d113.js" host=appname.herokuapp.com request_id=fce4e051-2880-4566-8e66-5cd3369a819f fwd="125.227.151.206" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=72ms status=404 bytes=1744 protocol=https
```

No other major error shown in the logs. Do you have any idea of how to solve or where to look for more details?

I apologize if this is a "stupid" question. It's the first time I actually deploy with webpack.

Comment: hi, can you resolve this? i have the same issue :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that my co-dev added /public/packs to .gitignore and therefore the directory wasn't pushed to Heroku

Comment: For me, I had to comment out `public/assets` but this is a workaround and not necessarily a solution. You shouldn't have to push all your packs to source control because they dirty up everything and don't need to be there. The web server should compile it and generate the packs for you, so you don't need to send it any. However, whatever works works haha. Thank you for this clever idea!